# Lagering Temperature and Time

Tags: lager, doppelbock

Ok, so this is my second batch of beer ever, and it's a lager (doppelbock). My plan is to let it sit in my garage cabinet for 3 weeks, then bottle and lager in the refrigerator for a couple months. I don't have a secondary fermenter, so I won't be racking it.

The *cough*Mr. Beer*cough* instructions say to ferment at 68-78 degrees for 2 weeks minimum (My first batch was a pale ale that I set on the kitchen counter for 3 weeks. It tasted fine, but a bit yeasty). The research I have done says I should ferment at 45-55 degrees. I put a test cup of water next to the keg to check temperature. As of yesterday (day 2) it was still just under 60 degrees. It's still cold and rainy out and the garage is the coldest place I have. If it warms up, I'll probably bring it inside to my bedroom closet (or the refrigerator?).

It's really hard to see what's going on because the keg is so dark, and the airlock is under the lid. What I'm wondering is if anyone here sees any fatal flaws with this plan, or has any suggestions to keep me from a disappointing end to a 3-month process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on whether the Mr.Beer doppelbock kit actually uses lager yeast. If they recommend 68-78F it very well just be a  clean ale yeast like american/california ale yeast.

The best thing is to see what happens as per the instructions.  Then change your practice the next time if the flavor warrants a change.

Have no fear though it will ferment at 60+ degrees, so you will make beer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't tell what kind of yeast it is from the website. Maybe I should contact them to be sure. It's their 'Defibrillator Doppelbock 7.0' recipe. I checked it last night. It has a nice foamy surface, about 3/16" thick. I held a bright LED flashlight to the edge and no light made it through - it is already nearly opaque. I moved the light toward the 'corner' of the keg and could see just enough to notice particles ascending and descending - I assume they are tiny pieces of hops. I'm thinking this is a good sign?

Comment: I went over my character limit. Sorry.  .-(  So, if this turns out to be an ale yeast should I change tactics and ferment and condition at room temperature for a shorter time, or does my current plan seem ok? Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I tried to edit my post because I need to learn to read, but I waited too long. What I *should* have said is, "If it does happen to be a lager yeast, would you recommend the colder longer process, or should I still stick with the instructions?" <hangs head in noobish shame>

Comment: I always say finish the way it is.  See what happens and learn something.  Make a change next time if you think you need one.